# Is there a way to read multiple files from a list parallelly in multiple thread in PySpark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list: `dates` that contains dates as its elements. All these dates are my file's partition columns. It is partitioned by `created_date` and `created_hour`.
The columns `created_date` & `created_hour` won't be there in the data as they are logical boundaries in the form of partitions.
I am iterating the list and processing each file as below.

method 1: Iterating items one by one

```
def process_data(dates):
    for d in dates:
        df = spark.read.orc(f's3://some_path/created_date={d[0:10]}/created_hour={d[10:12]}')
        df.withColumn('created_date', lit(d[0:10])).withColumn('created_hour', lit(d[10:12]))
        df.after_some_other_transformations()
        df.repartition(1, "created_date", "created_hour").write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy("created_date", "created_hour").format("orc").save(save_path)
```

My Code is running fine and is meeting my requirement. However I want to speed up to iterations and so I thought of implementing steps in the loop as below.

```
batch = 3
```

method 2: using batch

```
def process_data(dates, batch):
    for d in range(0, len(d), int(batch)):
        file_array = dates[day:day+int(batch)]
        df = spark.read.orc(*file_array)
```

Each file has its own partition column in `created_date` & `created_hour` and I can programatically parse them from the date I receive from the list: dates
At the end, I can use them as my partition columns to write the data into another s3 bucket.

Now we have 1000s of partitions in our file system and I don't want to process `created_date`->`created_hour` file every time and would like to process multiple files at a time.

I can pass the batch into spark read statement using `*` to read multiple files at a time. But with this approach, I cannot use the partition columns: `created_date` & `created_hour`.

If I have a batch size of 3, is there any way I can read three files in three seperate threads and process them independently so that I don't need to go thru 1000s of iterations every time.

Based on my partition columns, If my approach to process multiple files is not correct, is there any way I can address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the folder instead of individual files:

```
spark.read.orc('s3://some_path/')
```

You will get 2 additional columns in your DataFrame: `created_date` & `created_hour`.
You can then filter on these fields based on the array of dates you have, Spark will then read only the files under the appropriate folders.

That way you will not have to batch it yourself and sequentially load each file, you let Spark figure it out.

Source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#loading-data-programmatically

EDIT: This is not specific to Parquet, it works for most formats, including ORC.